# AuthenticationManagerBuilder's in memory authentication doesn't work when I try to register a new user during runtime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()` in order to save a user during runtime after a user makes a post request to the `/register` page. However, when I try to enter the same exact username and password during the login page the credentials doesn't get authenticated.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository; 

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;

    public void saveNewUser(User user) {

        UserDetails newUser = loadUserByUsername(user.getEmail()); 

        log.info("-----------------SAVE NEW USER CALLED---------------------");
        org.springframework.security.core.Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                newUser, null, newUser.getAuthorities());

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); 

        try {

            log.info("------------------IN MEMORY AUTH SUCCESSFUL-----------------");
            log.info(user.getEmail() + user.getPassword() );
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser( user.getEmail() ).password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode( user.getPassword() ))
                    .roles("USER");

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            log.info("--------------------NOT SUCCESFUL!----------------");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
      throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
              "No user found with username: "+ email);
        }
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true; 
        return  new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
          (
              user.getEmail(), 
              user.getPassword().toLowerCase(), enabled, accountNonExpired, 
              credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, 
              getAuthorities(user.getRole())
              );
    }

    private static List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities (String role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(); 

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

So after I register a user, the `savenewuser` method gets called and I'm granted authorization for the other protected parts of the app. I know it gets called because when I look at the debug console I get these results,

```
2019-07-23 12:48:15.203  INFO 47906 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.f.f.Security.MyUserDetailsService      : -----------------SAVE NEW USER CALLED---------------------
2019-07-23 12:48:15.203  INFO 47906 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.f.f.Security.MyUserDetailsService      : ------------------IN MEMORY AUTH SUCCESSFUL-----------------
2019-07-23 12:48:15.205  INFO 47906 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.f.f.Security.MyUserDetailsService      : asd@gmail.comasd
```

However when I navigate to the login page and enter the same username and password that I registered with I get an error.

The `inMemoryAuthentication()` works
When I try to set it during the config method.

```
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override 
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 


        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password( passwordEncoder().encode("password") ).roles("USER");

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

However it doesn't work when I call it in my `MyUserDetailsService` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably misunderstood the role of the [`AuthenticationManagerBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html). It's used to build an [`AuthenticationManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html) at the startup of the application. The typical use is in the overriden configure method of the [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) as you did:

```
@Override 
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password( passwordEncoder().encode("password") ).roles("USER");
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

If you use it by yourself, you have to call the [build method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/AbstractSecurityBuilder.html#build--) of the [`AuthenticationManagerBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html) after having configured it and somehow register the [`AuthenticationManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html) you just build.

Read the [topical guide : Spring Security Architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture) for a deeper understanding of Spring Security.

Comment: Thank you for the resources, however, I am still confused. From the guide, it says that "AuthenticationManagerBuilder is great for setting up in-memory authentication"

Which is my goal at the moment for the application I'm building. 

I am still confused about why the inMemoryAuthentication() method works for the webSecurityConfig class, but not in my UserDetailsService class.

Comment: Because when you use the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` as a parameter of the configure method of the `WebSecurityConfig`, it's used by the framework at startup. When you use the autowired `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` the framework is not aware of your modifications and doesn't use them.